# How can I show gender names in HTML template

Tags: python, django

Whenever I am signup for a customer on my website all the data are shown on my dashboard but in the gender field, showing me a number.
Check the below image to better understand:
[image]

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    GenderChoice = (
        ("0","Male"),
        ("1","Female"),
        )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GenderChoice, default=1)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show the template and view for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`get_FOO_display` method [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) that Django automatically creates for any field having choices.

In your template where you previously would have referred:

```
{{ customer.gender }}
```

You would instead use:

```
{{ customer.get_gender_display }}
```